# Android: Using SharedPreferences with a Tab Layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, sharedpreferences

So I learned about making tabs in Android using FragmentActivity from [THIS TUTORIAL](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html). So now I have a FragmentActivity that holds 3 tabs, which means within those tabs are three different Fragments.

**FragmentActivity class**

```
public class ProductSingle_Activity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager Tab;
    public TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    Context ctx = this;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_single);

.... and so on
```

And I have two Fragments that become the two tabs of the FragmentActivity:

**One Fragment:**

```
public class details_frag_activity extends Fragment {

    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_frag, container, false);

    }
}
```

So I have stored some information such as 'name' and 'description' in the SharedPreferences of the application.

```
SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("product_details", 0); 
//ctx being the context
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("pname", name);
editor.commit();
```

I want to access those information through one of the Fragments like this:

```
public class details_frag_activity extends Fragment {

    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_frag, container, false);

        SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("product_details", 0); 
//I cant access the ctx (Context). To avoid the error I just declared a local variable. I need to get the context of the FragmentActivity
        String pname = pref.getString("pname", null);
```

However I can't access the 'ctx' (Context) through the fragment. Is there a way to pass the context of the FragmentActivity to the Fragment Classes such that they can retrieve stored information from the SharedPreferences? OR is there a better way to access common information through the Fragments (Tabs)?

Comment: is my answer worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fragement class one method is there by using that you can get Context.

```
private Activity activity;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Just assign that method parameter to a field then you can access this activity reference as context where ever you want. because Activity is Subclass of Context.

Comment: Thank you it worked! :) But do you know how to share a string array through Shared Preferences?

Comment: @BenildusRatnayake  please explain briefly your requirement?

Comment: @balajikoduri I have an array of strings. Is there a way to share the array through SharedPreferences? Like putString, maybe a putArray?

Comment: there is a method in SharedPreferences like set.  preferences.edit().putStringSet(arg0, arg1).commit();  try this.

Comment: SharedPreferences spf;
  String[] strArr={"one","two","three"};
  Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
  set.addAll(Arrays.asList(strArr));
  spf.edit().putStringSet("key", set).commit();

Answer (score 2):

You can override `onAttach` method in your `details_frag_activity` and create the `ProductSingle_Activity` object inside `details_frag_activity` class
use this...

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = (ProductSingle_Activity) activity;
}
```

or simply try

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("product_details", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the previous answer, you can simply use:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("product_details", 0);
```